# What is command line command to disable "text to speech" on 30 macs via Remote Admin?

Tags: mac-osx

This question is posed as a means to deal with disruptive school kids using "text to speech" facility, hence the need for such command disabling it

Also can such command be made permanent?

Comment: Were they making it read bad words?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a brute force method, but you can rename the `/System/Library/Speech` folder or delete it altogether. You might also want to delete or rename the `/usr/bin/say` binary as they are likely to discover it as well. I've tested this on 10.6, and it is "permanent" in the sense that it will survive reboot.

You could send:

`sudo mv /System/Library/Speech /System/Library/Speech.disable`

and

`sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/say` to disable execution on the binary.